# How to update the status of the checklist with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to update the status of the checklist on click of a button. Can I achieve it by making individual ajax calls pertaining to the checklist item or can I achieve it by making one call and still update it as soon as it is completed.

I have attached the template of how it looks and what I am trying to achieve.

Sorry tried to upload the CSS images files, however not able to do that.

This how it looks

[image]

Thanks in advance.`

```css
div {
  width: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 30%;
}

li {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

img {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  text-align: middle;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pass {
  background: url('status1.png') no-repeat -2px -47px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.fail {
  background: url('status1.png') no-repeat -2px -70px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.inprog {
  background: url('status1.png') no-repeat -2px -25px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.pend {
  background: url('status1.png') no-repeat -2px -3px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4> Please Wait...... Performing checks on</h4>
  <ul>
    <li> check1 <img src="img_trans.gif" class="pass" /></li>
    <li> check2 <img src="img_trans.gif" class="fail" /></li>
    <li> check3 <img src="img_trans.gif" class="inprog" /></li>
    <li> check4 <img src="img_trans.gif" class="pend" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Remove the by default assigned classes (`pass`, `fail`, `inprog`, `pend`) and assign it on Ajax call success based on the status..

Comment: You should show here what you already got in your javascript code.

Comment: The answer here is very contextual, if the processing involved in each item is sufficiently high to justify sending them individually then that makes sense. Each item can update its corresponding status in the UI. Otherwise you might as well make a single call and update the UI in one go

Comment: You can't get intermittent updates from an ajax call with one large call. Instead, you will want to have nested ajax calls. Start call 1, on success of call 1 perform call 2, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, Rich and Matt. I was exploring if there are any other options of getting the intermediate results from ajax call. Point noted. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways

1)Make ajax call and prepare the content and append

2)Again make an ajax call and based on the response dynamically assign classes of your

```
(pass, fail, inprog, pend)
```